# I am creating a tool tip in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-validation-engine

```
<div id="divid"><a style="text-align: left" href="#" onclick="$('#divid').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Please enter your EIN / Employee Code with which you log into your PC', 'load')">Help Prompt</a></div></td>
```

This is my help prompt syntax.
 i have also inculded jquery.validationEngine-en.js

```
<script>
            jQuery(document).ready(function(){
                // binds form submission and fields to the validation engine
                jQuery("#FNAME").validationEngine();
            });

        </script>
```

## FNAME is id of my form.

I am getting Object expected error.Please provide me a solution

Comment: please add more code to help you

Answer (score 0):

Try putting the link outside the div:

```
<div id="divid">EIN</div>
<a style="text-align: left" href="#" 
 onclick="$('#divid').validationEngine('showPrompt', 'Please enter your EIN / Employee Code with which you log into your PC', 'load')">
   Help Prompt
</a>
```

Comment: it gives me object expected when clicked on help prompt..
i even tried putting the div outside .. not working